# Partial view not displaying view-model when inside serialized Div

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, razor

I have a working partial view that is updated using Ajax Jquery.

If I make a small required change the partial view no longer displays the returned view-model

This is the code that works.

This is the code from the cshtml file:

```
<input type="button" id="EmulatorSubmit" value="Receive UDP Messages" />
<p>
    <h4>Message Received</h4>
    <div id="receivePaneEmulator">
         @Html.Partial("_HttpResponse", Model)
    </div>
</p>
```

This is my jQuery:

```
$('#EmulatorSubmit').click(function (event) {
     if ($(this).val() == "Receive UDP Messages") {
         udpReceiveTimer = setInterval(getUDPMessages, 100);
         $('#EmulatorSubmit').attr('value', 'Stop Receiving UDP Messages');
     } else {
          clearInterval(udpReceiveTimer);
          $('#EmulatorSubmit').attr('value', 'Receive UDP Messages');
          cancelGetUDPMessages();
     }
});

function getUDPMessages() {
     $.ajax({
         url: "@Url.Action("ReceiveUDPMessage", "TestandDevelopment")",
         type: "POST",
         data: $('#UDPSensorForm :input').serialize(),
         datatype: "text",
         success: function (data) {
             $('#receivePaneEmulator').html(data);
         }
     });
};
```

Note that this line does nothing: data: $('#UDPSensorForm :input').serialize(),
because #UDPSensorForm does not exist because at this point I had not created it.  This is fine and not part of the problem.

This is my Partial:

```
@model Haptic_Theatre_Vibings_Control.Models.HttpViewModel
@Html.TextAreaFor(m => m.HttpResponse, new { @class = "form-control" , rows = "5" })
```

This is my Controller Action:

```
public ActionResult ReceiveUDPMessage(HttpViewModel httpViewModel)
{
   httpViewModel.HttpResponse = "Hello";
   return PartialView("_HttpResponse", httpViewModel);
}
```

The above works fine.  I click the EmulatorSubmit button and I get "Hello" displayed in the Partial.

However, I actually want to send some data from the view into the Action.
So I added in a Div with the ID of UDPSensorForm which is used in the jQuery to collect the data:

Amended cshtml:

```
<div id="UDPSensorForm">
    <h4>Port Nunber</h4>
         @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.HttpPortNumber, new { @class = "form-control input-sm" })
    <p></p>
    <input type="button" id="EmulatorSubmit" value="Receive UDP Messages" />
    <p>
        <h4>Message Received</h4>
        <div id="receivePaneEmulator">
             @Html.Partial("_HttpResponse", Model)
        </div>
    </p>
<    input type="button" id="EmulatorSubmit_Record" value="Record UDP Messages" />
    <p>
        <h4>Activity Note</h4>
        <div id="activityNote">
             @Html.TextAreaFor(m => m.ActivityNote, new { @class = "form-control", rows = "5" })
         </div>
    </p>
</div>
```

EmulatorSubmit and EmulatorSubmit_Record share the data in HttpPortNumber which is why I didn't just make 2 forms (they share a lot of other data. I have cut the code down for clarity)

I have added Jquery and Actions for the new button, EmulatorSubmit_Record.

The JQuery, Partial and Controller Action have not changed for EmulatorSubmit .

Now when I click EmulatorSubmit I can see the model in the Action and it has picked up HttpPortNumber.

I can see that the Partial view refreshes.

But the Partial view no longer displays "Hello"

Why has adding this Div stopped the Partial view from receiving the View-Model correctly?

EDIT:  If I move the Partial view outside the div then "Hello" is displayed.  Messes with my nice layout though :-(